# Weird behavior when firing PUT request at ruby on rails REST service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, put, rest-client

I have a rails application, in which I have a route and a controller for that route.
The route and request body are something like this:

```
put 'url/resource/:id' => 'controller#method'

{ 
   first_name: "george" 
}
```

and I want to test it using a rest client (the RESTClient plugin for mozzila firefox). When I fire the request without appending a 'Content-Type: application/json' header, the controller gets activated, the method runs and it fails at deserialization, as expected. 
However, when I append the header, the method in the controller doesn't even get to run, and I get a weird error:

```
ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError
Hash/Object not terminated at line 1, column 4 [parse.c:820]

with stacktrace:

actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:53:in `rescue in parse_formatted_parameters'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:32:in `parse_formatted_parameters'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:23:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__67324019__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
```

Any ideea what could be wrong? The same route with POST verb instead of PUT works without problems.